# Android : Access functionality of FaceManager like FingerprintManager

Tags: android, fingerprint, face, unlock

How to implement an acess class for FaceManager service like FingerprintManagerCompat in fingerprint?

direct acess give this error:

```
error: package android.hardware.face does not exist
import android.hardware.face.FaceManager;
                            ^
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says FaceManager is not available, to use biometric authentication (face and fingerprint) you should integrate [BiometricManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricManager) which replaced the now deprecated FingerprintManagerCompat.

**EDIT**

As quoted [here](https://source.android.com/security/biometric/face-authentication) what you want to achieve doesn't seem possible

> FaceManager is a private interface that maintains a connection with
> FaceService. It's used by Keyguard to access face authentication with
> a custom UI. Apps don't have access to FaceManager and **must use
> BiometricPrompt instead.**

Comment: yes, but BiometricManager is not flexible as i wish. i want to determine the available authentication sensor and which of them the user use.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible, I updated my answer